# Como implementar uma biblioteca que possui recursos similares ao jQuery?

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de criar uma biblioteca bem simples contendo somente as funções que mais utilizo, seguindo uma ideia semelhante as existentes no jQuery. Por exemplo:

Eu criei a seguinte função para obter um elemento:

```
var $ = function(el, index){
    if(index)
        return document.querySelectorAll(el)[index-1];
    return document.getElementById(el) || document.querySelector(el);
};
```

Alguns testes que fiz, no seguinte trecho de código:

```js
var $ = function(el, index){
    if(index)
        return document.querySelectorAll(el)[index-1];
    return document.getElementById(el) || document.querySelector(el);
};

$("minha-div-com-id").innerHTML = "pegou pelo ID";
$(".minha-div-com-class").innerHTML = "pegou pela classe";
$(".minhas-divs", 1).innerHTML = "pegou o primeiro elemento com classe '.minha-divs'";
$(".minhas-divs", 3).innerHTML = "pegou o terceiro elemento com classe '.minha-divs'";
```

```html
<p id="minha-div-com-id"></p>                  <!-- pelo id -->
<p class="minha-div-com-class"></p>            <!-- pela classe -->

<p class="minhas-divs" style='color:blue'></p> <!-- 1 -->
<p class="minhas-divs"></p>                    <!-- 2 -->
<p class="minhas-divs" style="color:red"></p>  <!-- 3 -->
```

Isso já atende o básico do que eu gostaria de fazer. Mas eu queria incluir algumas funções como no jQuery, por exemplo:

`$("foo").fazAlgo().eFazMaisAlgumaCoisa().eOutra();`.

Creio que estou meio longe disso pois minha função só me retorna um elemento no documento e o que eu estou buscando seria um *builder*. Talvez o termo esteja errado, mas conheço essa técnica por esse nome em outras linguagens.

Até consegui algo "mais ou menos", mas não sei se está correto. Segue o que consegui:

```js
(function(__window){

    var lib = {};
    __window.minhaBibioteca = lib;
    
    lib.alerta = function(args){
        alert(args);
        return lib;
    };
    
    lib.outroAlerta = function(args){
        return lib.alerta(args);
    };
    
})(window);


/**
 * Onde consigo usar assim:
 */

minhaBibioteca.alerta("Alerta {1º}")
              .outroAlerta("Outro alerta {1º}")
              .alerta("Alerta {2º}");

/**
 * ... que ainda não é o que estou buscando,
 * com o alert é simples, mas quando trata-se de manipular um
 * elemento, eu não sei como fazer...
 **/
```

Supondo que eu tenha uma função chamada `inner(str)` que basicamente insere o conteúdo/valor de `str` dentro do elemento HTML (`innerHTML`). Como eu faria para chamá-la assim:

```
$("foo").inner("Algum Texto");
```

?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Isso que você quer se chama encadeamento. Você precisa ter um objeto (enquanto no seu código você tem uma função), e todos os métodos dele retornam o próprio objeto. Um exemplo simples do princípio, usando um objeto literal:

```
var obj = {
    umMetodo: function() {
        console.log('um método');
        return this;
    },
    outroMetodo: function() {
        console.log('outro método');
        return this;
    }
}

var retorno = obj.umMetodo().outroMetodo();
//                  ^-- retorna obj!  ^-- idem!

// Isto é verdadeiro:
retorno == obj;
```

Para poder funcionar como no jQuery, onde `$` (ou `jQuery`) é uma função, é preciso que essa função retorne um objeto que represente o elemento selecionado, e não o próprio elemento como você faz hoje. Esse objeto é que dará acesso aos métodos que você quer encadear. Seu código não parece querer lidar com coleções, então isso é um problema a menos para resolver.

A primeira tentativa seria fazer a a função precisa retornar `this`, mas só isso não adianta. Numa chamada direta de função como `$()`, o `this` será sempre o objeto `window`, o que não ajuda. Você precisa que o `this` seja algo que faça sentido, que represente um elemento do DOM.

A solução é forçar que `$` seja chamada como função construtora, mesmo que a chamada não tenha sido `new $()`. Isso é simples de verificar. Quando você executa `new $()`, o `this` é definido como o objeto que está sendo instanciado, um objeto cujo tipo é a própria função construtora. Basta checar o tipo do `this`, usando este princípio:

```
function $(param, outro) {
    // chama novamente com new se o tipo não estiver certo
    if(!(this instanceof $)) return new $(param, outro);

    // ... faz o que precisar ...

    // só chega aqui se chamou com new
    return this;
}
```

Ainda faltam duas coisas: embrulhar o elemento nesse seu novo objeto e criar os métodos. O jeito mais fácil de embrulhar é guardar o elemento numa propriedade do seu objeto. Em todos os métodos que você quer encadear, ele estará disponível por meio da propriedade. Colocando essas duas coisas, seu código vai ficar parecido com isto:

```js
function $(el, index) {
    if(!(this instanceof $)) return new $(el, index);
    
    if(index) {
        this.el = document.querySelectorAll(el)[index-1];
    } else {
        this.el = document.getElementById(el) || document.querySelector(el);
    }
    
    return this;
}

// No protótipo do tipo, você define todos os métodos:
$.prototype.inner = function(txt) {
    this.el.innerHTML = txt;
    return this;
}
$.prototype.azul = function() {
    this.el.style.color = 'blue';
    return this;
}

// Teste
$('paragrafo').inner('testando').azul();
```

```html
<p id="paragrafo"></p>
```

Answer (score 7):

O código do JQuery é público, porque não ir dar uma espiada em como eles fazem pra tomar inspiração? :) Se você quiser uma dica, esses arquivos aqui contém a parte que define o "builder" do jQuery.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core/init.js

Voltando à sua pergunta, você estava certo em prever que o que você precisa é um "builder" ao invés de retornar a resposta do querySelectorAll diretamente. E é até isso que o jQuery faz: `jQuery("foo")` é um objeto da classe "jQuery" e é preciso fazer um `jQuery("foo").get(0)` para acessar o elemento DOM diretamente.

Para implementar isso não é muito difícil. Basta criar uma classe pro seu builder e botar todos os métodos que você quer nele. Os métodos "encadeáveis" como o seu "fazAlgo()" e "eFazMaisAlgumaCoisa()" também retornam builders (normalmente o próprio `this`) e os métodos "acessadores" como "get" e "toArray" returnam valores diversos e terminam a cadeia de métodos.

```
function toArray(x){
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(x);
}


function RenanQuery(el, index){
    //this._els são os elementos selecionados pelo seletor `el`.
    //Para ser uniforme, sempre armazenamos como um vetor.
    if(index != null){
        this._els = [ document.querySelectorAll(el)[index] ]
    }else{
        this._els = toArray( document.querySelectorAll(el) );
    }
}

$ = function(el, index){
    return new RenanQuery(el, index);
}

//Métodos acessadores retornam valores quaisquer
RenanQuery.prototype.get = function(n){
    return this._els[n];
}

//Métodos "encadeáveis" retornam o próprio this ou um outro objeto "RenanQuery"
RenanQuery.prototype.each = function(callback){
    for(var i=0; i<this._els.length; i++){
        callback.call(this._els[i], i, this._els[i]);
    }
    return this;
}

RenanQuery.prototype.inner = function(txt){
    for(var i=0; i<this._els.length; i++){
        setInnerText(this._els[i], txt);
    }
    return this;
}
```

A versão completa vai ter mais ou menos essa cara. A maior mudança que falta é permitir criar objetos RenanQuery a partir de coisas que não são strings seletoras. Por exemplo, seria bom poder criar um elemento RenanQuery a partir de um nó do DOM ou uma lista de nós de DOM.

Para fazer isso você pode botar um montão de ifs dentro do construtor do RenanQuery ou você pode mudar o construtor RenanQuery para algo mais baixo nível e botar a mágica toda no "$".

Comment: vou dar uma verificada :D

Comment: +1, é exatamente o que o jQuery faz, e inclui o mecanismo para tratar conjuntos de elementos.