# O que é Chainability?

Tags: javascript

O que é exatamente Chainability ?

É aplicável em outras linguagens além do Javascript ?

Pesquisei um pouco, mas o termo me lava para artigos desconexos, acredito que não sai oque exatamente procurar para entender tal conceito.

Comment: Possível duplicada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56168/129

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O termo "Chainability" vem do inglês "*chain*", que significa "cadeia" (não "cadeia" de prisão) ou "corrente". Logo, o termo significa "*habilidade de criar cadeias*".

**Chainability** é a capacidade, dentro da linguagem de programação, de um objeto criar *cadeias* (ou *encadeamento*) derivadas dele mesmo.

O jQuery é bom nisso:

```
$("#id")
.filter(".clickme")
.click(function(){
   alert("You are now leaving the site.");
})
.end()
.filter(".hideme")
.click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
  return false;
})
.end();
```

Veja as várias *cadeias* criadas para o mesmo elemento `#id`.

No JavaScript puro, um exemplo de *chaining* seria obter valores a partir de uma única função:

```
var Kitten = function() {
  this.name = 'Garfield';
  this.color = 'brown';
  this.gender = 'male';
};

var bob = new Kitten();

console.log(bob.name); // retorna "Garfield"
console.log(bob.color); // retorna "brown"
```

Em síntese, o conceito de "encadeamento" é quando um único objeto fornece múltiplos valores, instâncias ou funções. A vantagem disso é que você pode obter múltiplos resultados sem ter que repetir códigos.

> **É aplicável em outras linguagens além do JavaScript?**

Esta pergunta pode ser respondida pelos conhecedores de outras linguagens além do JavaScript, uma vez que nem todo mundo domina todas as linguagens de programação. Mas acredito que muitas outras linguagens avançadas possam ter a mesma habilidade.

**Fonte de pesquisa:**

- https://www.telerik.com/blogs/chainability-the-magic-of-jquery
- https://schier.co/blog/2013/11/14/method-chaining-in-javascript.html

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu tinha visto algo parecido só que não com tantas cadeias em Python : `Gui ().run ()` ... ( Nesse caso o Objeto ' Gui ' não é atribuido a nada, mas sim é simplesmente executado )