# Como criar uma function e chamar seus métodos sem usar new, semelhante ao $ do jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

O `$` (cifrão) do jQuery é uma *function*, contudo é possível acessar seus métodos como se fosse um objeto através do operador "." . Alguém poderia explicar, de que forma eu poderia fazer isso em uma function *func*, por exemplo?

[image: function func]

De forma mais esclarecedora, pretendo usar *func()* como também *func.each()* por exemplo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em JavaScript as funções são tipos especiais de objetos, e podem ter propriedades (incluindo outras funções) como qualquer objeto:

```js
function funcao(x) {
    console.log('função chamada');
}

funcao.propriedade = 10;
funcao.metodo = function() { console.log('método chamado') }

// Testes:
funcao();
console.log(funcao.propriedade);
funcao.metodo();
```

No jQuery a coisa é um pouco mais complexa porque todos os métodos vão no [protótipo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15239), a função `$` é um construtor, e ainda a biblioteca implementa [encadeamento de métodos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56179) das instâncias desse construtor. Mas no seu caso talvez baste o feijão-com-arroz acima (avise caso não baste).

Answer (score 6):

Você pode armazenar uma função em uma variável e utiliza-la para executar funções internas através de um objeto, este algoritmo implementa *[Javascript Module Pattern](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/javascript-modules-a-beginner-s-guide-783f7d7a5fcc)*.

```
var $fn = function() {
  return {
    alertar: alertar
  }

  function alertar(message){
    alert(message);
  }
}();

$fn.alertar("teste")
```

Você também pode implementar uma function através de `prototype`:

```
var $fn = function () {
    if (this instanceof $fn) 
        return this

    return new $fn;
};

$fn.prototype = {
    alertar: function (message) {
        alert(message);
    }
};

window.$ = $fn();
```

Comment: Dessa forma não responde minha questão, pois $fn não é uma function e sim um objeto. Ou seja  typeof $fn retorna "object" e não "function" como typeof $