# Fazer com que todas as funções do protótipo herdem um outro protótipo

Tags: javascript

Estou começando meus estudos com protótipos javascript, assim que comecei, me deparei com um problema que não consegui resolver. Segue o código

```html
var ComponentAction = function(component){
 this.comp = component;
}

ComponentAction.prototype.remove = function(){}
ComponentAction.prototype.addContent = function(){}

var Component = function(){}

Component.prototype.submitButton = function(){
    return new ComponentAction(this);
}
Component.prototype.alertButton = function(){
    return new ComponentAction(this);
}



let sb = new Component();
sb.submitButton().addContent('...');
```

É possível fazer com que a função **submitButton** ou qualquer outra função que faça parte de **Component** herde todos os métodos contidos em **ComponentAction** sem precisar retornar um **new ComponentAction(this)** em cada umas das funções de **Component**?

Comment: Tem mais de uma maneira de fazer isso, mas será que é a melhor opção? Por que não declarar os métodos diretamente no protótipo de `Component`?

Comment: Mas dessa forma eu conseguiria acessar o método addContent() como em sb.submitButton().addContent('...'); ?

Comment: @Edgar para encadear métodos dessa maneira tens somente de retornar o `this` (a instância da o objeto) no fim de cada método. Dá uma olhada a esta resposta do bfavaretto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56179/129

Comment: @Sergio, agora que vi a resposta ficou muito claro. Obrigado a ambos por suas contribuições!